# Document compiles in Overleaf, but just hangs without error message in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, overleaf

I am trying to use a PhD thesis template I was given. The code compiles in Overleaf without alterations, but for some reason in TexStudio, the code never compiles. It doesn't produce any error messages, just hangs until I stop it. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{icldt}
\usepackage{./ThesisStyle}

\title{~}
\author{~}
\date{~}
\department{Physics}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\include{./Introduction/IntroductionMain}
\appendix
\appendixpage

\bibliography{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

The files `Bibliography.bib` and `Introduction.tex` are just blank files.
`icldt.cls` is here:

```
%%
%% This is file `icldt.cls',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{icldt}
    [2011/01/29 v2.0 Imperial College London Dissertation Template]



\newcommand*{\@supervisor}{}
\newcommand*{\@university}{}
\newcommand*{\@college}{Imperial College London}
\newcommand*{\@department}{}
\newcommand*{\@field}{}
\newcommand*{\@degree}{}
\newcommand*{\@diploma}{}
\newcommand*{\@declaration}{}
\DeclareOption{university}{%
 \renewcommand{\@university}{University of London}}
\DeclareOption{imperial}{%
 \let\@university\empty}
\DeclareOption{PhD}{%
 \renewcommand{\@degree}{Doctor of Philosophy}
 \renewcommand{\@diploma}{Diploma of Imperial College London}}
\DeclareOption{MSc}{%
 \renewcommand{\@degree}{Master of Science}\let\@diploma\empty}
\DeclareOption{BSc}{%
 \renewcommand{\@degree}{Bachelor of Science}\let\@diploma\empty}
\DeclareOption{DIC=off}{%
 \let\@diploma\empty}
\DeclareOption{DIC=on}{%
 \renewcommand{\@diploma}{Diploma of Imperial College London}}
\DeclareOption{declaration=off}{%
 \let\@declaration\empty}
\DeclareOption{declaration=on}{%
 \renewcommand{\@declaration}{%
 I herewith certify that all material in this dissertation which
 is not my own work has been properly acknowledged.}}
\DeclareOption{doublespacing}{\AtBeginDocument{\doublespacing}}
\DeclareOption{onehalfspacing}{\AtBeginDocument{\onehalfspacing}}
\DeclareOption{titlepagenumber=off}{%
 \AtEndOfClass{\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{empty}}}
\DeclareOption{titlepagenumber=on}{%
 \AtEndOfClass{\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{plain}}}
\DeclareOption{paper=a4}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrreprt}}
\ExecuteOptions{onehalfspacing,titlepagenumber=on,imperial,PhD,
declaration=off,paper=a4,pagesize=auto,11pt,twoside}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[pagesize=auto]{scrreprt}
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\RequirePackage[left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]%
 {geometry}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}
\newcommand*{\college}[1]{\gdef\@college{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\gdef\@department{#1}}
\newcommand*{\field}[1]{\gdef\@field{#1}}
\newcommand*{\declaration}[1]{\gdef\@declaration{#1}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\secpd}[2]{\frac{\partial^{2} #1}{\partial #2^{2}}}
\newcommand{\secpdx}[3]{\frac{\partial^{2} #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d} #1}{\mathrm{d} #2}}
\newcommand{\secderiv}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} #1}{\mathrm{d} #2^{2}}}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left\langle{#1}\middle|{#2}\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle{#1}\right|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|{#1}\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\macca}[1]{\color{red}{\bf{#1}}\color{black}}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{
\begin{titlepage}
 \par
 \clearpage
 \thispagestyle{\titlepagestyle}
 \null\vfill
 \begin{center}
  {\titlefont\huge \@title\par}
  \vskip 3em
  {\Large \lineskip 0.75em
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
   \@author
  \end{tabular}\par}
  \vskip 1.5em
  

 %\begin{figure}[h!]
 %\begin{center}
% \includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{IC_crest.pdf}
 %\end{center}
 %\end{figure}
 
  {\Large \@date \par}
  \vskip \z@ \@plus3fill
  \ifx\@supervisor\@empty \else
  {\Large Supervised by \@supervisor \par}
  \fi
  \vskip 2em
 \end{center}\par
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  Submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of\\
  \@degree\ of  \ifx\empty\@university{\@college}\else{the \@university}\fi
  \ifx\@diploma\@empty\fi
 \end{minipage}
 
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \centering\large
  \vskip 0.5em
  \ifx\@department\@empty \else \par Department of \@department\fi \\
  \ifx\@university\@empty \else \@university\par\fi
  \@college \\
  Prince Consort Road \\
  London SW7 2AZ \\
   

 \end{minipage}

 \ifx\@declaration\@empty\else{
 \cleardoublepage
 \chapter*{Declaration}
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \@declaration
 \par\vspace{3cm}
 \hfill\@author
 \cleardoublepage
 }\fi
\end{titlepage}
}
\newcommand{\makededication}{
 \ifx\@dedication\@empty \else
 \clearpage
 \thispagestyle{plain}
 \null\vfill
 {\centering \Large \@dedication \par}
 \vskip \z@ \@plus3fill
 \cleardoublepage
 \fi
}
\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
\chapter*{Abstract}\thispagestyle{plain}}{\cleardoublepage}
\endinput


%%
%% End of file `icldt.cls'.
```

And the file `ThesisStyle.sty` is:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \def\pdfshellescape{1}
 \usepackage{epstopdf}
%

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress% 
             ]{natbib}
%            \usepackage{hypernat}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcommand{\pvec}[1]{\vec{#1}\mkern2mu\vphantom{#1}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{$\rightarrow$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2032}{'}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B1}{$\alpha$}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B3}{$\gamma$}
\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
\DeclareMathOperator\var{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator\cov{Cov}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al. }}

\bibliographystyle{plainnatnourl}

\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}

\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{ \chaptername \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\fancyhf{} % delete current setting for header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headsep}{1.0ex} % make space for the foot rule
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=colon}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\pdfminorversion=5
\usepackage[ pdftex, 
    plainpages = false, 
    pdfpagelabels, pdfpagelayout = SinglePage, 
    bookmarks, bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,breaklinks = true,
    linktocpage, pagebackref,colorlinks = true, linkcolor = black,urlcolor  = black,citecolor = black,anchorcolor = black, hyperindex = true,
     pdfproducer=TeXShop,pdfstartview=FitV, 
    %hyperfigures 
    ]{hyperref}

\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2#1#3}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, I believe that `Overleaf` updated into latest version, so better you to update the setup and try

Comment: Just a first guess: Since your document class is not included in any standard distribution, the problem is probably that your local engine cannot access the document class nor your self-defined package. In Overleaf it is sufficient to simply copy the corresponding files into the directory. But on a local installation this is not so easy. If you are using MikTeX you could try to install the .cls and .sty file according to these instructions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2066/82926

Comment: @Nico thank you! I'm using TexLive 2021, I've tried copying the .cls and .sty files into C:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @mgmf46 Your code works fine for me, better to change the code from `\usepackage{./ThesisStyle}`, to `\usepackage{ThesisStyle}` and keep all the files into your working path, also updated TeXLive into latest release

Comment: @mgmf46 Partially yes, but after this you have to make TexLive familiar with the added files (update your database). How to do this depends on your operating system. On Linux (Ubuntu) this could be done from the command line with mktexlsr.

Comment: @Nico if the class or the sty could not be found the compilation wouldn't hang, there would be an clear error.

Comment: It seems that this might be a fault with an old TexLive distribution. Downloading TexLive 2022 and recompiling seems to fix the problem